# Scheduled messages are sent at difference of 5 hours 30 minutes in Twilio and Sendgrid api

Tags: python, django, twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api

I am working on a Django application where I have used twilio to send sms and whatsapp messages and the sendgrid api for sending the emails. The problem occurs in scheduled messages in all three. For example, if I have schedule an email to be sent at 06:24 PM(scheduled time is 06:24 PM), then I am receiving the email at 11:54 PM, hence the difference is of 5 hours and 30 minutes. The same problem also arises in sms and whatsapp.

I think the problem might be due to the timezone. I am scheduling the messages from India and twilio account is in USA. And, the time difference of 5 hours 30 mins is due to the UTC format as India is 5 hours 30 mins ahead of UTC. But I am not getting any solution for this.

Also the time is specified as the UNIX time. I am getting a datetime object whose value is like: "2022-09-13 11:44:00". I am converting it to unix time with the "time module" of python. Hence the code looks like:

```
message = MAIL(...)
finalScheduleTime = int(time.mktime(scheduleTime.timetupple()))
message.send_at = finalScheduleTime
```

In the above code, scheduleTime is the datetime object.

So, is there any specific way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Show us how you're specifying the time in your API call.

Comment: There is a datetime object where the value is "2022-09-13 11:44:00". I am converting this to Unix time using the time.mktime() as the sendgrid api accepts the format of unix time stamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the answer of [philnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash), the sendgrid api and twilio is scheduling the messages in UTC and we are generating it in IST without timezone attached. Hence first of all we need to attach the timezone and then convert it in the UNIX Timestamp. Refer to the following code:

```
scheduleTime = scheduleTime.astimezone()
finalScheduleTime = int(time.mktime(scheduleTime.timetupple()))
message.send_at = finalScheduleTime
```

Hence, this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Twilio and SendGrid are scheduling the messages in UTC and you are creating your time in IST without a time zone attached, so the time is being interpreted as UTC and thus sent 5 hours 30 minutes out.

I'm not a python expert, so I may be wrong here. But, I think using `mktime` is incorrect here and you should be using [`gmtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime).

```py
message = MAIL(...)
finalScheduleTime = int(time.gmtime(scheduleTime.timetuple()))
message.send_at = finalScheduleTime
```

Alternatively, you don't have to convert the datetime to a time first. You can change the datetime's timezone from your local one to UTC:

```py
import pytz

utcdatetime = scheduleTime.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
```

Then turn that into a timestamp:

```py
message.send_at = int(utcdatetime.timestamp())
```

Comment: Here the gmtime won't work as it always returns time_struct dictionary, but I got a way from your initial explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what actually worked for the benefit of anyone else with this problem?

Comment: We have posted the answer below.